# Showing convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin{\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)} \right)$

Tags: real-analysis

So I have proven the limit 
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty}n^3 \left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin{\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)} \right) = \frac{1}{6}.
$$
I then have to prove that the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin{\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)} \right)$$
converges using the limit. I don't know how to go on from here and I'm really confused about using the limit for this task.

Comment: Do you know the  [Limit Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_comparison_test)?

Comment: @SewerKeeper : what are we comparing this to?

Comment: It's not in our book, so I don't think we can use that. 
@SewerKeeper Thank you for editing the post!

Comment: @Arjang to $\frac{1}{n^3}$, right?

Comment: @ZevLoveX which tool can you use?

Comment: Using the site that Sewer provided.
-Ratio test
-Root test
-Integral test
-Direct comparison test
-Cauchy condensation test

Comment: Why the obsession with this particular series?

Comment: @AnginaSeng Part of an assignment

Comment: Others have asked about it recently....

Comment: @SewerKeeper : yes, well spotted. I can't see how I would write it down clearly though.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Can you point me to it?

Comment: @ZevLoveX note that your series is a series of positive terms. Hence since the general term is asymptotic to $1/n^3$ by your limit, it follows that your series converges or diverges with the series $\sum 1/n^3$. Since this is convergent, yours also is.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\epsilon\in(0,\,1/6)$. Some $N\in\Bbb N$ satisfies $n^3(1/n-\sin(1/n))\in(1/6-\epsilon,\,1/6+\epsilon)$ for all integers $n\ge N$. Since $A:=\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}$ is finite, $\sum_{n=N}^\infty(1/n-\sin(1/n))\in((1/6-\epsilon)A,\,(1/6+\epsilon)A)$. This sum of positive reals is therefore convergent.